remove white spaces till /n in js, and put it inside a array
I'm looking for a way of put all three lines of my html inside an array, but those three lines will be breaked in 3 index. My array has to be a 3 length array, with a line in each index.
I see that i can accomplish that by rearrange my paragraph removing white spaces and making them more close, right in the html file. So i would like to know if there are others ways using only JS for that. This is what i have done so far, when i click on convert button, and look at console log, there a confuse array, with more than 3 index and full of white spaces:

i would like to remove those white spaces and have just 3 index with those 3 text lines.
I've tried trim(), but it only remove from the first index, the second and third not.



//let stringg = document.querySelector('input');

let btn = document.querySelector('button');
let p = document.querySelector('.example-text');

let x = p.innerText.toString();
let y = x.split('\n');

btn.onclick = function(){
    console.log(y);
};
<p class="question">4. Write a JavaScript program to convert a 
                       comma-separated value (CSV) string to a 
                       2D array of objects. 
</p>
<p class="example-text" style="display: none ;">
        this,is,text,example
        lets,go,try,if,i
        can,solve,this issue</p>
<div class="butt-out">
  <button id="btn-press">convert</button>
</div>




Could you please edit your question and show us an example of the expected output?

What's wrong with the code you have?  Note that the <p> tag does, in fact, have 4 lines.  The content starts immediately after the closing >, so that first empty line is included.

i edit my question, its like you said, im look for a way by using only js of removing that white space immediately after > and my array be only those three lines. is that possible ?

Remove whitespace with .trim().

i know if i rearrange my html file ater  i can remove those white space, but i would like to do that by js only.

it remove only in the first line, the second and third are still there.

Something like x.split("\n").map(line => line.trim())

First, you should not be setting up event handlers by setting a function equal to the event property. While legal, it is an older technique that has several drawbacks. Instead, use the modern standard of element.addEventListener(eventName, callback).
Next, all the work that the callback should do should be in the callback.
See inline comments below for specifics about your issue:


const p = document.querySelector('.example-text');

// This is the modern way to set up event handlers:
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", function(){
  // First, clean up leading or trailing spaces from the whole string
  let x = p.textContent.trim();  
  
  // Split the string at newlines into an array,  then loop over that array and 
  // trim each item within the array and return that item into the new array
  // returned by the map() function.
  let y = x.split('\n').map(function(item){
    return item.trim();
  });
  console.log(y);
});
<p class="question">4. Write a JavaScript program to convert a 
                       comma-separated value (CSV) string to a 
                       2D array of objects. 
</p>
<p class="example-text" style="display: none ;">
        this,is,text,example
        lets,go,try,if,i
        can,solve,this issue</p>
<div class="butt-out">
  <button id="btn-press">convert</button>
</div>



Now, based on what you have shown you want your results to be, you are not looking for a 2D array of objects (that would be an array nested within an array). What you've shown is a 1-dimensional array consisting of 3 strings.
If you really want an array of objects, I suspect you're looking for this:


const p = document.querySelector('.example-text');

// This is the modern way to set up event handlers:
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", function(){
  // First, clean up leading or trailing spaces from the whole string
  let x = p.textContent.trim();  
  
  // Split the string at newlines into an array,  then loop over that array and 
  // trim each item within the array and return that item into the new array
  // returned by the map() function.
  let y = x.split('\n').map(function(item,idx){
    let obj = {};            // Prepare an object that will be inserted into the array
    
    // Set the key of the new object to the index of the item in the array and
    // the value of the key to the array item with spaces trimmed off
    obj[idx] = item.trim();
    
    return obj;  // Return the new object into the array that will be returned by .map()
  });
  console.log(y);
});
<p class="question">4. Write a JavaScript program to convert a 
                       comma-separated value (CSV) string to a 
                       2D array of objects. 
</p>
<p class="example-text" style="display: none ;">
        this,is,text,example
        lets,go,try,if,i
        can,solve,this issue</p>
<div class="butt-out">
  <button id="btn-press">convert</button>
</div>




my goal was only remove those white spaces, im trying to solve the question (on P paragraph) chunk by chunk, till reach the whole problem in the end. your first code just help me btw, thanks
